# sklearn requirements installation with pip: ensure that binary wheels are used

Tags: sklearn-pandas

In the sklearn [installation guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installing-the-latest-release) for the latest version (1.3.1) it mentions that you can install dependencies with pip, but says

**"When using pip, please ensure that binary wheels are used, and NumPy and SciPy are not recompiled from source"**

What does this mean and how would I go about ensuring that?